# Why am I getting the error "Expected class, delegate, enum, interface or struct"

Tags: c#

Can anyone tell me why am I getting this error? This is my first post to this forum. The research I have done to fix the problem on my own says I may have an improper curly brace somewhere, but I cannot locate it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

---

```
using System;

    class Program
    {
    //declare constant
    const double ANGLES_FROM_RADIANS = 57.295779513082323;

    static void Main()
    {

        //declare vairiables
        double xc = 0.0;
        double yc = 0.0;
        double radius = 0.0;
        double theta = 0.0;

        //call methods
        double GetUserInput (ref double xc, ref double yc);
        double CalcCoords (double xc, double yc, ref double radius, ref double theta);
        double Output (double radius, double theta);
     }


    //method prologue

    static double GetUserInput (ref double xc, ref double yc)
    {
        xc = 0;
        yc = 0;
        while (xc = 0)
        {
     Console.WriteLine("Please enter a possitive, non-zero value for the  x-ccordinate   of a point.");
            xc = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if (xc <= 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error, x must be greater than zero.");
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a possitive value for the y-coordinate of a point.");
        yc = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Return Console.WriteLine("Your Coordinates are ({0},{1})", xc, yc);
    }

    //method prologue
    static double CalcCoords (double xc, double yc, ref double radius, ref double theta)
    {
            {
            radius = Math.sqrt((xc * yc) + (xc * yc));
            return radius;
            }
            {
            theta = Math.Atan(yc / xc) * ANGLES_FROM_RADIANS;
            return theta;
        }
    }

    //method prologue
    static double Output (double radius, double theta)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("For your polar coordinates:");
        Console.WriteLine("Distance from the origin: {0:f}", radius);
        Console.WriteLine("The angle (in degrees) from the x-axis is: {0:f3}", theta);
    }   

        Console.ReadLine();

    }//End Main()
    }//End class Program
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Last brace is extra mate .This one -

```
}//End Main()
```

Also why last `Console.ReadLine();` is `misplaced`. Shouldn't it be in under any method scope?

**EDIT**

I don't know what your code suppose to do. It contains lot of `errors` and the `intent of code` is not clear too. This code is compiling though -

```
class Program
    {
        //declare constant
        const double ANGLES_FROM_RADIANS = 57.295779513082323;

        static void shdg()
        {
            //declare vairiables
            double xc = 0.0;
            double yc = 0.0;
            double radius = 0.0;
            double theta = 0.0;
        }

        //method prologue
        static void GetUserInput(ref double xc, ref double yc)
        {
            xc = 0;
            yc = 0;
            while (xc == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter a possitive, non-zero value for the  x-ccordinate   of a point.");
                xc = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                if (xc <= 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error, x must be greater than zero.");
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a possitive value for the y-coordinate of a point.");
            yc = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("Your Coordinates are ({0},{1})", xc, yc);
        }

        //method prologue
        static double CalcCoords(double xc, double yc, ref double radius, ref double theta)
        {
            {
                radius = Math.Sqrt((xc * yc) + (xc * yc));
                return radius;
            }
            {
                theta = Math.Atan(yc / xc) * ANGLES_FROM_RADIANS;
                return theta;
            }
        }

        //method prologue
        static void Output(double radius, double theta)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("For your polar coordinates:");
            Console.WriteLine("Distance from the origin: {0:f}", radius);
            Console.WriteLine("The angle (in degrees) from the x-axis is: {0:f3}", theta);
        }
    }//End class Program
```

Comment: So I removed the last brace, and it did not clear my errors...any other thoughts??

Comment: Have you deleted the last `Console.ReadLine()` lying around at last in the class code.?

Comment: The program is supposed to use 3 methods. 1 that takes input from the user and validates it. a second that converts the input (polar coordinates) and calculates the distance from the origin and the angle. And the last method is supposed to display the info calculated in method 2.

Answer (score 2):

The extra last brace `}//End Main()`

Answer (score 0):

`main method` or a `method` doesnt contain `class` or other methods

a `class` contains a single `main` method(which is the entry point to your app) **or/and** multiple `methods`

Also your `//call methods` is invalid..you have to pass values or variables.

Comment: A class can be without an entry point and the op did have an entry point in his code.

Comment: @CodeIgnoto thts why i said **or/and**

Comment: I am not sure what you mean Fake.It, sorry I am very new to this.

Comment: @user1763538 u cannot have other methods in a method.ur code is actually including all the methods into main which is illegal..

Comment: @fake.it What do you mean by including methods in main.op seems to be just calling the methods from main.

Comment: @CodeIgnoto the op has closed the braces at the end calling it `//End Main()`.. i guess he thinks that main method can include other methods that's y he closed it at the end